# Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser as a desktop browser

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I develop an Windows Phone 8 application that shows html5 content in `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser`.
Is there a way to make the WebBrowser control interpret the HTML content as a normal desktop web browser?

Comment: What do you mean? It's Windows Phone IE10. Are you saying that there's a web site that is serving different content based on user agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with the initial navigation, you can specify additional headers to be sent, including the `User-Agent`:

```
var ua = "User-Agent: MyDesktopAgent";
// IE10 desktop: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
// IE11 desktop: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com", null, ua);
```

Beyond that, there's not much you can do other than wait for web sites to move to a more responsive design that adapts to screen size and capabilities rather than looking at browser `User-Agent` strings.